# Can I change my date format from 20140129 to 01/29/2014 using VBA?

Tags: vba, date, excel, date-format

I am just trying to figure out the easiest way to change the date format on a huge spreadsheet but the biggest problem seems to be that the year and month/day are switched around. I need it to be mm/dd/yyyy but currently it is yyyymmdd. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html - record yourself changing the format to whatever you want. there are a plethora of date formats - just right click and click 'change format'

Comment: The problem is on my spreadsheet the year is first. I looked thru all the formats offered and none of them will move the year to the end. They try to change 20140129 to 20/14/0129 which obviously causes an error.

Comment: Are you in the Western Hemisphere? It might be you have a version of excel that is localized to use non-western date formats. In any case this should answer your question: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-HA102809474.aspx#_Toc320186183

Comment: You also might want to verify that the dates you have are actually dates and not just strings/text. You can do this with IsNumber(cell_ref)

Comment: I'm sorry Stepan, I probably should have said that it is really just a string. It came from another report so Excel is not recognizing it as a date. It is probably best if I leave it as a string but I need it in the mm/dd/yyyy format for a macro I'm using on another system. So I guess really all I need to do is take a string and take the first 4 characters and move them to the end and then put a couple of /'s in there. Forgive me for not being clear, I still am trying to catch on. Thanks!

Comment: @novak: Did you try the solution given below? It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I change my date format from 20140129 to 01/29/2014 using VBA?

You mean Like this?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim temp As String
    Dim D As String, M As String, Y As String

    temp = "20140129"

    Y = Left(temp, 4)
    M = Mid(temp, 5, 2)
    D = Right(temp, 2)

    '~~> This will give you 01/29/2014
    Debug.Print Format(DateSerial(Val(Y), Val(M), Val(D)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Followup from comments.

Use this code (TRIED AND TESTED). I am assuming that the dates (as string) are stored in Col A from `A1` onwards in say `Sheet1`

```
Sub Test()
    Dim temp As String
    Dim D As String, M As String, Y As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            temp = CStr(.Range("A" & i).Value)

            Y = Left(temp, 4)
            M = Mid(temp, 5, 2)
            D = Right(temp, 2)

            .Range("A" & i).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

            '~~> This will give you 01/29/2014
            .Range("A" & i).Formula = Format(DateSerial(Val(Y), Val(M), Val(D)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Next i


    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: @Downvoter. Care to comment?

Comment: Looks O.K. to me..............

Comment: Downvote wasn't from me but this looks very close to what I'm trying to do. But I need to use it for hundreds of dates that all differ but are in that format yyyymmdd.

Comment: @novak: Use a loop :)

Comment: @novak: See my updated post. You may have to refresh the page.

Comment: That worked! I was having a hard time there for a minute getting it adapted to my spreadsheet but that worked great! Thanks!

Comment: @novak: Glad to be of help :)